# When resizing my div, content falls out and i get a scrollbar to adjust the screen horizontally. (site to wide)

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Hello i get this problem when i try to resize my window for mobile, that the pseude element :after and :before (the 2 lines next to my title) fall out of the site and create a horizontal scrollbar for the user (which i do not want).

my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvgua1s2/1/ try resizing it to mobile to see the problem.

html:

```
 <section class="slogan wow">
        <h1 class="slogantitel wow fadeIn"> Ontdek ons</h1>
    </section>
```

css:

```
   .slogan {
  position: relative;
  height: 30%;
  min-height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slogan-content {
  text-align: center;
}

h1.slogantitel {
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;  
  color: rgb(95,55,17);
  text-align: center;
   position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}

.slogantitel:before, .slogantitel:after {
    content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.slogantitel:after {
    margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `overflow: hidden;` for `h1.slogantitel`, it will prevent h-scrollbar from appearing.

Answer (score 2):

try overflow:hidden; for h1 tag.

```css
.slogan {
  position: relative;
  height: 30%;
  min-height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.slogan-content {
  text-align: center;
}

h1.slogantitel {
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;  
  color: rgb(95,55,17);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
   position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}

.slogantitel:before, .slogantitel:after {
    content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.slogantitel:after {
    margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
 <section class="slogan wow">
            <h1 class="slogantitel wow fadeIn"> Ontdek ons</h1>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this would be reduce the font in mobile is that it will fit fully in mobile.

```
h1.slogantitel {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```